# Cosa sono i "cugini d'acquisto"?

Tags: word-usage, meaning

Nel racconto *Fino a che dura il Sole* di Italo Calvino ho letto (il corsivo è mio):

> La famiglia di nonna Ggge sono in non so quanti, sparsi un po' per tutte le costellazioni: e ad ogni cataclisma lei s'aspetta d'incontrarne qualcuno. Il fatto è che non si sbaglia: ogni volta che il Colonnello esplode nello spazio si ritrova in mezzo a cognati o a *cugini d'acquisto*.

Ho cercato cos'è un "cugino d'acquisto", ma non l'ho trovato in nessuno dei dizionari che ho consultato. Immagino dal contesto che siano i cugini della moglie, ma si può chiamare anche così al marito della cugina (in modo simile al "cousin-in-law" inglese)? Facendo una cerca su Google ho trovato anche l'espressione "cugino acquisto", che penso sia lo stesso, ma non so se sia più comune. Che ne dite?

Comment: È proprio “cugino acquisto”? Non sarà “cugino acquisito”, che è la formulazione che mi è più familiare (ed equivalente alla locuzione della domanda)?

Comment: @DaG: Ho trovato "cugino acquisto" perché, basandomi nell'espresione di Calvino, sono le parole che ho cercato. Per esempio, si trova qui: http://www.girodivite.it/Il-cugino-di-Howard-Beach.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dal contesto credo che nell'esempio riportato nel [link](http://www.girodivite.it/Il-cugino-di-Howard-Beach.html) ci sia un errore tipografico: *d'acquisto* lo si trova con il significato di *cugino indiretto*, sinonimo di *cugino acquisito* (pare senza troppe distinzioni), ad esempio [qui](https://books.google.it/books?id=RoVi_AuxLocC&lpg=PT29&dq=cugino%20d'acquisto&hl=it&pg=PT29#v=onepage&q=cugino%20d'acquisto&f=false) e [qui](https://books.google.it/books?id=ejxDeoFlNv8C&pg=PT71&dq=cugino+d%27acquisto&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjtpavFr5zKAhUEPBQKHcUQCI8QuwUIQjAF#v=onepage&q=cugino%20d%27acquisto&f=false), ma *cugino acquisto* [non si trova](https://www.google.it/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=cugino+d%27acquisto&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gfe_rd=cr&ei=wsyQVoH2O8bD8ge-yIyQBg#channel=fs&tbm=bks&q=cugino+acquisto). Dunque la forma utilizzata da Calvino (e cioè *cugino d'acquisto*) è meno comune di *cugino acquisito*, come evidenziato da @DaG, ma presente anche in testi di altri autori; di *cugino acquisto*, a parte il link da te riportato, non riesco a trovare altri esempi in rete.

---

La forma *parente acquisito* designa più genericamente un legame di parentela indiretto, secondo il [significato](http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario_italiano/A/acquisito.shtml) dell'aggettivo *acquisito*:

> 1 Fatto proprio, **assimilato nel corso del tempo e non** innato o **naturale** [...] || *parente a.*, **non consanguineo**.

Comment: Vuoi dire non che si trova in Google libri?

Comment: E, come dice @DaG, la forma più comune sarebbe "cugino acquisito"?

Comment: Vedo che nei dizionari appare l'espressione "parente acquisito".

Comment: È vero che *acquisito* è più comune, ma è facile vedere con Google che le edizioni di Calvino sono unanimi nell'usare l'espressione come l'ha scritta l'OP. Riporterei i permalink di google libri, ma sono troppo lunghi per questo commento. Quindi direi proprio che non si tratta di un errore tipografico, Calvino l'ha scritta proprio così.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni: L'errore tipografico non si riferisce a Calvino, ma al link che ho messo nel mio commento alla domanda.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni, come dice Charo ho parlato di (e riportato il) link, non mi riferivo al testo citato nella domanda.

Comment: Oh, ok, avevo capito male, scusate.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni, nessun problema! :)

Comment: Charo, ho editato la risposta aggiungendo maggiori spiegazioni.